# I think javascript is turned off in my Firefox and I can't turn it back on

Tags: firefox

I usually go to tools > options > content. There used to be a checkbox - "Enable javascript there".

The checkbox is no longer there. I am using version 34 of Firefox.

If I go to 9gag.com anything that requires javascript, like autoload or showing comments do not work.

Also I can no longer see any google ads.

Comment: If you are using it on this website, and you receive no errors, then JavaScript is working.

Comment: JavaScript is enabled by default.  You need to use an add-on if you want to disable it.  See: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages

Comment: Why do you think it’s disabled? [This page](http://www.enable-javascript.com/) provides a test, although I don’t know how reliable it is.

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually you don't need an add-on to completely disable it, but it's of course easier than passing through the `about:config` screen.

Answer (score 3):

Old versions of Firefox had this checkbox indeed. It has been removed a while ago because JavaScript is too pervasive nowadays to have enough websites working with JavaScript disabled. You can go at `about:config`, and look for the preferences named `javascript.enabled`, it should be `true` if JavaScript is enabled. The checkbox you used to see was controlling that preference.

Comment: It's called `javascript.enabled`, not `javascript.enable`.

Comment: @MihaiTodor: Indeed... sorry for the typo, will correct.

Answer (score 2):

Check your installed addons (type about:addons in your address bar). Maybe you have something like [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) installed.

On second thought, the option that you are looking for, has been moved to about:config and it is called "javascript.enabled". See [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967344) for details.